# Draw image into area between two concentric circles in Xcode / objective-c

Tags: objective-c, image, cocoa-touch, geometry, masking

I have an image (its actually circular) and wish to only draw the part of that image that corresponds to the area between two concentric circles, the outer one is fixed, the inner one can adjust in size.

The outer concentric circle will always correspond to the outside edge of the image - but a "hole" needs to be left in the drawn image - corresponding to the size of the smaller concentric circle.

I'm trying to do this in objective-c for iOS - to draw a variable-sized "viewfinder" control.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, the term for a circular disk with an inner circular disk cut out, is an "annulus".

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the standard case to use `CGContextEOClip`. Haven't checked this code, but something like:

```
CGContextRef ctxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, outerCircle);
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, innerCircle);
CGContextEOClip(ctxt);
//Draw your stuff
```

Comment: You would need to use `CGContextEOClip`.

Comment: Fixed to use `CGContextEOClip`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most performant solution would probably be to use a `UIImageView` and apply a `CAShapeLayer` as the mask of its layer.

Example:

```
UIImage *image = ...;
CGFloat ringWidth = 20.0;
CGRect outerCircleRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
CGRect innerCircleRect = CGRectInset(outerCircleRect, ringWidth, ringWidth);
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:outerCircleRect];
[path appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:innerCircleRect]];
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
imageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

You'll have to include the QuartzCore framework for this to work.

When you change the radius of the inner circle, you can simply assign a new path to the shape layer. This can even be animated.

Comment: Thanks so much, omz! This worked great. I'm a bit rusty (very rusty) on my geometry, so this was a GREAT help. Peter